# How to convert 0/1 to sign efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

Look at the following function, where `a` is an unsigned byte 0-255, and `b` is a float:

```
def convert(a, b):
    if a & 0x80:
        return -b
    return b
```

It negates `b` if the first bit of `a` is set, but does nothing when it isn't. One could think that this isn't that cool, since conditional statements ruin the branch prediction in the CPU. Therefore one would try to convert this into a computation.

But I only found this solution, which doesn't look that efficient:

```
def convert(a, b):
    return (-1)**(a & 0x80) * b
```

Which one is more efficient? Does the compiler simplify the second one? Is there a better way?

Comment: Did you benchmark your code?

Comment: Do you apply this function to a arrays?

Comment: @max9111 originally this wasn't a function. I just isolated that. I saw a code that used exponentiation to convert the GW-Basic floats to modern floats, and I was wondering if that's okay. This is a doc about those: https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/viewchm.php/hs/gwbasic.chm/tokens.html  But I've found a relatively optimal implementation in the meantime, by using the branching.

Comment: If performance matters, you can use Numba or Cython. If you run this type of algorithms on arrays (avoiding function call overhead) you get 2 to 3 orders of magnitude speedup. There things like branch prediction matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is Python. There is no compiler in the sense you're probably thinking of. Assuming you're using CPython (the reference interpreter), *everything* runs through a loop over a gigantic switch statement that reads and interprets each byte code as it goes. Your worries about branch prediction are irrelevant here; there will be half a dozen CPU level branches in *every* operation you perform, between the `switch`, the type checks, the dynamic function pointer lookup and call, etc. A distant jump might hurt the data cache a little when it ends up reading a byte code a few hundred bytes away instead of the next byte code, but branch prediction (or lack thereof) is not the issue (a 100% predictable jump would have the same issue).

Basically, whatever you do here that might work in C and get optimized to ideal code by the compiler's optimizer *will not work* in CPython. So don't bother. Write your complete code, profile it if it's too slow, and then work to optimize the "hottest" (most called) parts. You're engaged in premature optimization here, and really should stop.

If I were you, I'd go with option #1 (possibly replacing `if a & 0x80:` with `if a >= 0x80:` since the former needs to return an `int` which must then be truth-tested more expensively, while the latter returns `bool` directly, which is the cheapest thing to truth-test), as it's straightforward and unlikely to be terrible; only investigate other options if your program is too slow, and profiling says this particular bit of code is *the* hot spot.

Comment: FYI, I did do local microbenchmarking. Option #1 and #2 were basically the same when `a` was less than 128, but #2 was *much* slower (~3x longer to run) when `a` was greater than or equal to 128 (which make sense; Python doesn't have an explicit optimization for `-1 ** x`, so it ends up performing several pointless multiplications of `-1` and `1` to compute `-1 ** 128`). Option #1 replacing `a & 0x80` with `a >= 0x80` was even faster (20-40% lower runtime, depending on whether negation was needed).

Answer (score 2):

`(-1)**(a & 0x80)` calculates power so it's very inefficient. In fact you can replace that with `1 if exponent & 1 == 0 else -1` with exponent being `a & 0x80`. But it's even easier to get 1 and -1 from 0 or 1 by doing `x*2 - 1`

Some non-branching versions

```
return (((a >> 7) << 1) - 1)*b;
return (((a >> 6) & 0x02) - 1)*b;
return math.copysign(b, -(a >> 7));
return math.copysign(b, -(a & 0x80));
```

Comment: I'd considered including a `math.copysign` example, but decided against it because `math.copysign` coerces inputs to `float` and returns `float`; even if you cast it back to `int`, you can lose data if `b` is a 53 bit or larger `int` (above that limit, `float` can't represent every `int` value).

Comment: @ShadowRanger but the condition is that `b is a float` so no worry about that

Comment: And now I feel like an idiot having completely missed that. Whoops! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the creative examples!